# HOW to get LOW touch point argument for each touch point in UWP by C#

Tags: c#, api, uwp, touch, multi-touch

I need to filtrate touch point in an UWP app.  I need to filtrate touch point according to timestamp of a touch point, and get coordinate or id of the touch point.

In a WPF application , I can get necessary data of touch point by using `TouchFrameEventArgs` class, and using the method `GetTouchPoints()`.

But, In UWP app, what should I use? I want to get the first occurred touch point after a specific event occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, generally speaking, touhc, mouse and pen input in UWP is abstracted to a single event set dealing with [**pointers**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/input/handle-pointer-input).

When you handle a pointer event like `PointerDown`, you get an instance of [`PointerRoutedEventArgs` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.input.pointerroutedeventargs). This class will help you identify a specific pointer using the `Pointer.PointerId` property. This a unique identification you can use to check for the pointer that raised this event. You can store the pointer IDs you have encountered in time which should provide you with the behavior you are requesting.

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply. I also found that the touchhittest event and event arg class.

Comment: If that solves the problem, please consider accepting the answer as solution :-)